# JScript: Take as input an array of strings, return new array containing only strings with fewer than five characters

Tags: javascript

```
function fiveChar(inputArray) {
    var output = input.join();
    return output;
}

console.log(fiveChar(['lion', 'gorilla', 'elk', 'kangaroo']));
```

How can I make this only return `lion` and `elk`, given they're under five characters?

Thanks!

Comment: `return inputArray.filter(x=>x.length <5)`

Comment: `input.filter(s => s.length < 5).join()`

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a loop?

Comment: @raisesHand `filter` is a looping mechanism. But yes you can manually achieve this using `for`. Create dummy array and push necessary element in it and return it

Comment: @raisesHand: Yes. You write a loop, and do the comparison inside it, pushing to a new array for the ones that you want to keep. But if that caveat was important, it needed to be in the question.

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27131984/218196

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` to filter the array down into a new array with strings that have a `.length` less than 6 characters.

```
function fiveChar(inputArray) {
  return inputArray.filter(function(in) { 
    return in.length < 6;
  });
}
```

Comment: We don't need *yet another* answer to "How do I filter an array?"