# How to delete all elements from the array but retain specific element by value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good day guys! I have encounter some problem. I want to delete all the data from the array but doesn't delete that 1 data based from value.

example:

```
key = '2' 
array = [ 
         'data1': 'foo',
         'data' : 
                 {
                  'id' : '1', 
                  'id' : '2', 
                  'id' : '3'
                 }
         ]

result = [
          'data1': 'foo',
          'data' : 
                  {
                   'id' : '2'
                  }
         ]
```

that's all thank you

Comment: You can use `filter` method to do so. Please search on google before doing any type of questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I only keep items of an array that match a certain condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131984/how-can-i-only-keep-items-of-an-array-that-match-a-certain-condition)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter()` and compare the value with `key`.

```js
const key = 'foo';  
const array = ['foo', 'box', 'tree', 'bar'];
const result = array.filter(x => x === key);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: how about for nested arrays sir?

Comment: @JofeeanOgario Give some example by updating the question.

Comment: @JofeeanOgario Your data is not valid. You can't use `key:value` inside `[]`(arrays).

Comment: @JofeeanOgario And try it yourself first. And then again update the question with the code you have tried. Then ask me for help.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way will be to reassign the array or create a new array with the result

```js
const key = 'foo';
let array = ['foo', 'box', 'tree', 'bar'];
/*array = new Array(key); //be carefull if yoy are using this and the key is singular numeric value*/
array = [key];
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Why `new Array(key)` whynot just `[key]`

Comment: Still its in correct it doesn't involve the elements of `array` anywhere.

Comment: it's not mentioned that key will not be in the array. And it also mentions `one data` for me it doesn't make sense to iterate through the array for that.

Comment: OP said _"I want to delete all the data from the array but doesn't delete that 1 data based from value."_.